# Words for "piano"

Tags: музыка

I am a beginner at Russian, interest triggered by the availability of masses of old Russian scores at IMSLP. (So the first words I learnt were для, хора, фортепиано, оркестра and others in the genitive!)

Anyway, I have learnt three words already for "piano":

- фортепиано : as in Сюита для двух фортепиано -- what it says in scores
- пианино : "upright piano"
- рояль : "grand piano"

Today I found this dialog, which says that people at a music school learn пианино...

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sp8hXo9HdpE

So the question is: in ordinary conversation, how do I refer to the instrument I play? (Which is an upright at home, but a grand when I have the chance...)

Thanks for any help

Comment: In ordinary conversation people (non-musicians) usually say "пианино", though sometimes it's just wrong. Otherwise see @Roman's answer.

Answer (score 3):

"Пианино" and "рояль" are two kinds of "фортепиано". The 1st one has vertical string set, the 2nd one - horizontal.

So the answer is: say "**Фортепиано**" in the general case, and "пианино" and "рояль" when you talk about these specific kinds of "фортепиано".

For example,

- Я умею играть на фортепиано
- У меня дома есть пианино
- Я вернулся с концерта - за роялем был мой любимый исполнитель!

Comment: You can add that people who study music at music schools very often refer to the instrument as "фо-нó", a contraction of "фортепиано".

Comment: Спасибо! You have confirmed the dictionary definitions, but I was rather interested in the apparent cases which don't quite follow this. Like the dialog I linked to which includes "Здесь можно научиться... на пианино, на скрипке, ..." I guess there might be different ways in which musical specialists and non-musicians talked about this, so @Yellow Sky's comment above is also helpful.